# Rails' render is generating bizarre, subtly wrong content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, actionview

I've got an app that hosts simple html pages for people. Some of whom use tables for design layout. (Not me, I swear!) For some mysterious reason, render breaks these layouts in Internet Explorer.

Here is the simplest way I've been able to reproduce the issue.

When I save an html file into public/ and access it through Mongrel, it appears fine in all browsers. If I use the following code to render the file, it gets funky:

```
render :file => '[app_directory]/public/sample.html'
```

Internet Explorer creates an empty text node for each newline, which leads to gaps in the table. The raw html is apparently *identical*, but when served with render it is somehow changed in a way that makes Internet Explorer unhappy.

I'd be terrifically grateful for any pointers on how to stop this. Thanks!

### Edit 1: The mystery deepens...

I have figured out how to get Chrome to have the same error. Here is code that works in Chrome, and is broken in IE:

```
# tab_controller.rb
render :inline => tab.public_html
```

But when I change this to use an external ERB template, the strange whitespace shows up in Chrome as well:

```
# tab_controller.rb
@html = tab.public_html
render 'show'

# show.erb
<%=raw @html %>
```

I'm sure there is an explanation for this, but the more I dig the stranger it gets.

### Edit 2: Headers

Here are the response headers that IE gives for the statically served file:

```
Response        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection      close
Date            Fri, 05 Aug 2011 00:33:20 GMT
Last-Modified   Thu, 04 Aug 2011 23:38:21 GMT
Content-Type    text/html
Content-Length  913
```

And here are the response headers that IE gives for the content produced via render. The content that has the issues:

```
Response         HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection       close
Date             Fri, 05 Aug 2011 00:28:18 GMT
Content-Type     Text/html
X-UA-Compatible  IE=Edge
ETag             "43d392ddbbcf3856ced3de672005c26f"
Cache-Control    max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie       _rails_static_html_session=[session stuff]; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Runtime        31.964569
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

### Edit 3: Code

You can (I hope) reproduce the issue by putting the following code in any random controller:

```
html = "<html>\n<head>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n<table width='520' height='870' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>\n  <tr>\n    <td align='center' valign='top'><div align='center'>\n      <table width='520' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>\n        <tr>\n          <td><img src='.' width='520' height='314' /></td>\n        </tr>\n        <tr>\n          <td><img src='.' width='520' height='320' /></td>\n        </tr>\n        <tr>\n          <td><img src='.' width='520' height='166' /></td>\n        </tr>\n        <tr>\n          </tr>\n      </table>\n    </div></td>\n  </tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>"

render :inline => html
File.open('/railsappdirectory/public/sample_html.html', 'w') {|f| f.write(html) }
```

When you access this with Internet Explorer through the rails app, there will be gaps between the images. When you view the html file as a static asset, there will be no gaps.

Comment: Are you using Explorer for the public view as well as when you use `render`? IE renders content differently than other browsers.

Comment: Yes. Haha, and I'm keenly (bitterly) aware of the fact that IE renders content differently than other browsers. I love how you put that. :)

Comment: This could be related to content headers. What happens if you use render_to_string to get the raw text?

Comment: James, I think you might be right about headers. I just tried render_to_string, and it appeared to be absolutely normal markup.

I'll edit the question to add information on the headers that appear with the problem and without it.

Comment: try to see if this works. I use similar code to render 404 pages for some requests and works fine on rails 3.0.4. `render '/public/sample.html', :layout => false`

Comment: Thanks Rubish, but that didn't do it. I tried that, and `render :file => '/public/sample.html'`, and neither worked. :/

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it so this question is marked as answered. Interesting issue, thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: Will do, Andrew. Thanks for the pointer! I'm a long time lurker who's just getting the hang of actually contributing here. :)

Comment: ...I guess I don't have enough reputation to immediately answer my own questions, so I'll do it tomorrow. Unless any of you want to copy-paste the "Solved!" bit from above, and I'll select it as correct.

Comment: That would be a reputation ninja. :) Better do it yourself.

Comment: I would have thought that it would give the person who posted it reputation, and I thought it would be silly for me to answer my own question and get points for it. Haha, turns out it was the reverse. I just googled and found a [list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) of where reputation comes from. Thanks for helping me learn this stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a simple php file to serve the same content with different headers, and found that the following header rails was using caused the problem:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
```

A comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807605/rails-3-automatically-adding-x-ua-compatible-header) explained how to stop rails from serving this header. In your config/environments/*.rb files, ensure that the following setting is false:

```
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = false
```

Thanks everybody for helping!